# Saving data into solr with pysolr get rejected 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items''

Tags: python-3.x, solr, pysolr

I'm using pysolr to save a list of classes into my local solr database, my problem is that when i encode my list of classes with jsonpickle, the query is rejected with this message, although if i print the json generated by josnpickle i get no problem saving the data into solr.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3b6d9f42d0ec> in <module>()
     27 json=str(jsonpickle.encode(coreData, unpicklable=False))
     28 print(json)
---> 29 solr.add(json)

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysolr.py in add(self, docs, boost, fieldUpdates, commit, softCommit, commitWithin, waitFlush, waitSearcher, overwrite, handler)
        878 
        879         for doc in docs:
    --> 880             el = self._build_doc(doc, boost=boost, fieldUpdates=fieldUpdates)
        881             message.append(el)
        882 

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysolr.py in _build_doc(self, doc, boost, fieldUpdates)
        798         doc_elem = ElementTree.Element('doc')
        799 
    --> 800         for key, value in doc.items():
        801             if key == NESTED_DOC_KEY:
        802                 for child in value:

    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

my code:

```
from solrq import Q
import pysolr
import jsonpickle
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from Model import Twitter



#conexion a solr
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/twitter')

#query
query = Q(label="none")
results = solr.search(query)


print("Saw {0} result(s).".format(len(results)))

#testing the query
for result in results:
    print("-->".format(result['content']))

#creating a new class with data    
twit = Twitter("000002","content text","some label")  
#list of twitter classes
coreData=[]

coreData.append(twit)
#encoding to json
json=str(jsonpickle.encode(coreData, unpicklable=False))

print(json)
#saving to solr
solr.add(json)
```

This is what prints after encoding the list of classes into json `[{"content": "content text", "id": "000002", "label": "some label"}]`
as i said before if i substitute the json variable with this string the data is saved but i have no idea why, even if cast as a string like this `solr.add(str(json))` get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that [pysolr](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/blob/master/pysolr.py) for method add

> Requires `docs`, which is a list of dictionaries. Each key is the
>           field name and each value is the value to index.

You need to create dictionary from your object, not strings. You could do it by calling `vars` on an object

```
coreData=[]
coreData.append(vars(twit))
solr.add(coreData)
```

Comment: edit: i just realized that i don't need jsonpickle anymore to save data in solr thank you!

Comment: @B.J.A.A. I've checked it, should work. Could you share your Twitter class?