# Pysolr issue while adding json data to index

Tags: json, python-3.x, solr, pysolr

I am trying to add a document to a collection in Pysolr. I have first installed solr from homebrew and started the solr server.

For the client, I am following the documentation listed [here](https://pypi.org/project/pysolr/3.1.0/). The data I have is in JSON format. I had initially created python objects and converted them to json format but that didn't work. This is how I was trying to add data to Solr.

`

```
import pysolr

# Create a client instance. The timeout and authentication options are not required.
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/test', timeout=10)


#How you'd index data.
solr.add([
{
    "id": "doc_1",
    "title": "A test document",
},
{
    "id": "doc_2",
    "title": "The Banana: Tasty or Dangerous?",
},
```

])`

I got the error:
 `File "/Users/sushmitamallick/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysolr-3.1.0-py3.8.egg/pysolr.py", line 442, in _scrape_response TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`
, so I tried doing a test run using a python dict instead after referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824780/saving-data-into-solr-with-pysolr-get-rejected-attributeerror-str-object-has):

`

```
import pysolr

# Create a client instance. The timeout and authentication options are not required.
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/test', timeout=10)

d = dict()
d["id"] = 1
d["name"] = 'sushmita'

#How you'd index data.
solr.add(a)`
```

This is failing with
  `File "/Users/sushmitamallick/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysolr-3.1.0-py3.8.egg/pysolr.py", line 680, in _build_doc AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

I have also tried passing in a Json array instead of a single entity, still have the same error.

Any leads would be appreciated.

I am expecting to ingest data into Solr with this command which I then plan to query with

`results = solr.search('sushmita')`

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)